# Manipulating the variable mass free particle Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

During a calculation involving a variable mass free particle we are told that $$ \sqrt{f(x)}\hat{p}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}} \hat{p}\sqrt{f(x)} = \sqrt{\frac{f(x)}{m(x)}} \hat{p}^2 \sqrt{\frac{f(x)}{m(x)}} + \frac{\hbar}{2} f(x) \left(\frac{3}{1}\frac{m'(x)^2}{m(x)^3} - \frac{m''(x)}{m(x)^2}\right)$$

Where $\hat{p} = -i \hbar \frac{d}{dx}$, $m(x)$ is a position dependent mass and $f(x)$ is an arbitrary function of position. Yet the best I can find, by applying the product rule, is that
$$  \sqrt{f(x)}\hat{p}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}} \hat{p}\sqrt{f(x)} =  \sqrt{f(x)} \Big[ \left(\hat{p}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}}\right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}}\left( \hat{p} \sqrt{f(x)}\right) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}} \left(\hat{p}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}}\right) \left( \hat{p} \sqrt{f(x)}\right) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}}\left( \hat{p}^2 \sqrt{f(x)}\right) \Big] =  \frac{\sqrt{f(x)}}{m(x)}\left( \hat{p}^2 \sqrt{f}\right) -\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\frac{m'(x) f'(x)}{m^2}$$
Would anybody be able to explain what step/idea I am missing? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were told wrong. Your target expression is wrong, including the missing power of $\hbar$ in the last term. Part of your problem is the maelstrom of superfluous symbols, like the outside *f*s and the implied arguments. You are actually asked to process
$$
{\mathfrak G}=\hat{p}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m }}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m }} \hat{p},
$$
For which you know
$$
[\hat p, \frac{1}{\sqrt{m }}]= \frac{i\hbar }{2 m^{3/2 }} m',
$$
so that
$$
{\mathfrak G}=\hat{p}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m }}\frac{1}{\sqrt{m }} \hat{p}
=\left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{m }} \hat{p}+  \frac{i\hbar }{2 m^{3/2 }} m'  \right )\left ( \hat{p}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{m }}- \frac{i\hbar }{2 m^{3/2 }} m' \right ) \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{m }} \hat{p}^2  \frac{1}{\sqrt{m }}   +  \frac{\hbar^2 }{4 m^3} m' ^2   -i\frac{\hbar}{2\sqrt{m }}[ \hat{p},   \frac{ m' }{ m^{3/2 }}] \\
=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{m }} \hat{p}^2  \frac{1}{\sqrt{m }}   +  \frac{\hbar^2 }{4 m^3} m' ^2   -\frac{\hbar^2 m''}{2 m^2  } +    \frac{3\hbar^2  m'^2 }{ 4m^{3 }} \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{m }} \hat{p}^2  \frac{1}{\sqrt{m }}   +  \frac{\hbar^2 m'^2}{ m^3}    -\frac{\hbar^2 m''}{2 m^2  }  ~.
$$